# Optional Parameter error in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, optional-parameters

I am trying to create a function that will take a vector of true or false. This vector represents a binary number and I want to convert it to an integer number in the function
This is my code

```
let rec int_of_vec x ?(i=1) = match x with
      [] -> 0
    | True::t -> (1*i) + int_of_vec t ~(i:(i*2))
    | False::t -> 0 + int_of_vec t ~(i:(i*2))
;;
```

But I keep getting errors dealing with the optional parameter
I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong as I am pretty new to Ocaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an optional parameter to handle something that is usually handled with a helper function. For more idiomatic OCaml style you might want to rewrite using an inner function that *always* takes a parameter `i`.

Optional parameters in OCaml don't work well as the last parameter. You'll get fewer complaints from the compiler if you make `i` the first parameter of your function.

The Boolean constants in OCaml are `true` and `false`.

The syntax for supplying an optional parameter looks like `~i: (i * 2)`. The `~i:` is a single token that can't be broken apart.

Aside from these smallish problems, this is good code. (Assuming your vector is supplied with least significant bit first.)

Comment: Thank you very much I just used your edits and it worked. But I'm curious why would a helper function be more appropriate in this case then an optional parameter

Comment: Unless this is part of a larger computation that assembles multiple vectors into one number, the type of your function includes an extraneous parameter that is not useful to the caller. This makes the function harder to understand and more error prone to use. To put it another way, the `i` parameter is part of the implementation and shouldn't be part of the interface (the type).